# Mi footer no ingresa en mi maquetación con Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, layout, footer

Apenas estoy aprendiendo maquetación con flexbox en HTML Y CSS. Este es mi problema, estoy realizando un layout sencillo como practica pero no logro encajar mi footer en su lugar.

Al principio tenia los cuatro en la clase MAIN y no funciono así que decidí separarlo en un DIV a los tres que considere están mas relacionados como el nav, section y footer pero aun así se presenta el mismo problema al igual que si los hubiera dejado por fuera del DIV de clase PART-1. ¿alguien sabe porque no ocupa el lugar vacío?

```css
.container{
    background-color: gray;
    width: 500px;
    height: 620px;
    margin: 70px auto;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
.header{
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
}
.main{
    background-color: wheat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 470px;
    display: flex;
}
.part-1{
    background-color: gold;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.aside{
    background-color: darkkhaki;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.nav{
    background-color: seagreen;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.section{
    background-color: indianred;
    width: 75%;
    height: 400px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.footer{
    background-color: darkseagreen;
    width: 75%;
    height: 70px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/entiende/styles/maque_2.css">
    <title>maquetacion dos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header class="header">1</header>
        <main class="main">
            <div class="part-1">
                <nav class="nav">2</nav>
                <section class="section">3</section>
                <footer class="footer">5</footer>
            </div>
            <aside class="aside">4</aside>
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comparto una imagen donde muestro como deseo que quede la maqueta. Gracias por ayudarme

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es muy importante a la hora de implementar un diseño ser capaz de dividirlo correctamente, si no luego es imposible hacer que se vea como quieres. Tu diseño en la imagen tiene dos zonas principales claras, un header y un cuerpo debajo. Y ese cuerpo tiene TRES zonas claras, tres columnas verticales! Y la columna de en medio está a su vez dividida en dos. Este es el diseño que has de implementar, que es la división lógica más sencilla que se puede hacer de tu diseño, teniendo siempre la misma orientación en los bloques en vez de mezclar divisiones verticales y horizontales tal como haces en tu código.

```css
.container{
    background-color: gray;
    width: 500px;
    height: 620px;
    margin: 70px auto;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
.header{
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
}
.main{
    background-color: wheat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 470px;
    display: flex;
}

.column {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.column:first-child {
    max-width: 25%;
}

.column:last-child {
    max-width: 20%;
}

.aside{
    background-color: darkkhaki;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.nav{
    background-color: seagreen;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.section{
    background-color: indianred;
    height: 400px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.footer{
    background-color: darkseagreen;
    height: 70px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/entiende/styles/maque_2.css">
    <title>maquetacion dos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header class="header">1</header>
        <main class="main">
            <div class="column">
                <nav class="nav">2</nav>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <section class="section">3</section>
                <footer class="footer">5</footer>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <aside class="aside">4</aside>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Quité el div que metes en medio (`.part-1`), que lo veo innecesario teniendo el .main, pero puedes mantenerlo si quieres, siempre y cuando contenga las tres columnas dentro claro :)

Lo importante es tener las columnas (`.column`) con el flex para permitirles adaptar el tamaño y luego setearles un ancho máximo a los dos laterales para que no pasen del 20-25% como indicas, lo cual lo he hecho con los selectores `:first-child` y `last-child` de la clase `.column`. Cualquier duda aquí estamos.